# Right-click on a link sometimes opens in same tab instead of showing context menu so I can open it in a new tab, especially on Dictionary.com

Tags: firefox, context-menu, hyperlink, links, browser-tabs

I'm sure everybody does this: I like to go to "root" site and cherry pick links that interested in, opening them each in a new tab.  I do this a lot for news sites like Google news.  I also do it for [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/) for synonyms of a word I have.

Recently, I noticed this has stopped working consistently.  Now, when I do that on synonyms listed on Thesaurus.com, it automatically loads the link in the current tab instead of presenting the context menu which would allow me to pick "open in a new tab".

Is this a problem with Firefox (I'm on 47.0 now, Windows 7, x64) or a problem with sites like Dictionary.com?  The links look "normal", i.e. when I hover over them, they show the URL in the Firefox status bar.  I know there are sometimes special kinds of links that run code which don't always invoke the context menu, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

[image]

Comment: Happens quite regularly with sites that use links which aren't links, or with links where they capture mousedown events via Javascript and don't discriminate between them. I strongly suspect the problem is with the site itself, not your web browser, but you can always try with some other browser (for example, since you are on Windows, you might try to do the same thing with Internet Explorer and see if it makes any difference; if it doesn't, that's a very strong indication that the web site is doing something fishy, but if it works fine, that's not a guarantee that it isn't).

Comment: FYI,  right click wors fine on Chrome, however middle click doesn't open in a new tab (which it should).